# MTOM/XOP implementation for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, xml-parsing, mtom, xop

Our rails app requires to receive and parse SOAP requests with MTOM/XOP attachments (http://www.w3.org/TR/xop10/). Are there known solutions for rails?

Here is an example of a request (taken from the link above):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: Multipart/Related;boundary=MIME_boundary;
    type="application/xop+xml";
    start="<mymessage.xml@example.org>";
    startinfo="application/soap+xml; action=\"ProcessData\""
Content-Description: A SOAP message with my pic and sig in it

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; 
    charset=UTF-8; 
    type="application/soap+xml; action=\"ProcessData\""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <mymessage.xml@example.org>

<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'
    xmlns:xmlmime='http://www.w3.org/2004/11/xmlmime'>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:data xmlns:m='http://example.org/stuff'>
      <m:photo 
  xmlmime:contentType='image/png'><xop:Include 
    xmlns:xop='http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include' 
    href='cid:http://example.org/me.png'/></m:photo>
      <m:sig 
  xmlmime:contentType='application/pkcs7-signature'><xop:Include 
    xmlns:xop='http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include' 
    href='cid:http://example.org/my.hsh'/></m:sig>
    </m:data>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://example.org/me.png>

// binary octets for png

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://example.org/my.hsh>

// binary octets for signature

--MIME_boundary--
```

Rails successfully parses simple multipart requests, but looks like it completely doesn't know what to do with MTOM attachments and we are about to write our own parser. Thanks!